# The field named 'r' in mongodb log

Tags: mongodb, profiler, database

when `mongodb` database profiler is activated, we receive a lot of information, most of it is explained in the official documentation. However, I couldn't find anything about a field named **r**

For example

```
numYields:467606 locks(micros) r:991899178 nreturned:101
```

What is that field?

Answer (score 1):

Possibly it's a lock mode: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/database-profiler/#system.profile.locks

I'm sure you have already seen this, but anyway – hope this would help.

Comment: Then what's the number after it?

Comment: @Mansuro: microseconds, I guess.

Comment: @Mansuro yep: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/database-profiler/#system.profile.locks.timeAcquiringMicros

Answer (score 1):

According to [serverStatus documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/v2.6/reference/command/serverStatus/#serverStatus.locks...timeLockedMicros.r):

> The r field reports the amount of time in microseconds that any
>   database has held the local read lock.